# MySql get matching names from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have 4 different tables named as

```
ps_product
ps_product_lang
ps_category_lang
ps_manufacturer
```

The table for ps_product is like this

```
id_product  id_manufacture  id_category_default
1           1               5
2           1               7
3           1               9
4           1               10
5           1               11
6           1               11
```

ps_product_lang is like this

```
id_product   name 
1           Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts
2           Blouse
3           Printed Dress
4           Printed Dress
5           Printed Summer Dress
6           Printed Summer Dress
7           Printed Chiffon Dress
```

ps_category_lang is like this

```
id_category  name
1            paints
2            Home
3            Women
4            Tops
5            T-shirts
6            Tops
7            Blouses
```

ps_manufacturer table is like this

```
id_manufacturer  name
1                Fashion Manufacturer
```

Now here I want that when I will select name with like then it will show the datas from those names. Like when I
will search some thing like `'paint%'` then it should show matching names from product name, product category and manufacturer name
So can someone tell me how to join those tables to get the values? Any help and suggestions will be really appreacilble. Thanks

Comment: I would setup mysql full text search for an efficient solution.

Comment: Show the expected output you want from the tables when u search so that its clear what u want.

Answer (score 1):

Try Inner Join on all your four tables and then do "and" between all the name fields if you want you field to start with say paint in any of those three tables like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ps_product pp INNER JOIN ps_product_lang ppl  ON pp.id_product          = ppl.id_product
                   INNER JOIN ps_category_lang pcl ON pp.id_category_default = pcl.id_category
                   INNER JOIN ps_manufacturer pm   ON pp.id_manufacturer     = pm.id_manufacturer
WHERE ppl.name like 'paint%'
AND   pcl.name like 'paint%'
AND   pm.name  like 'paint%'
```

Note: If you want to search paint to be present in any of those three tables, then use "OR" between the conditions instead of "AND".

Comment: How Can I select only name. Because I have a large database and select * is doing slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pl.name, cl.name, m.name
FROM ps_product p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product AND pl.name LIKE 'paint%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON p.id_category_default = cl.id_category AND cl.name LIKE 'paint%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_manufacturer m ON p.id_manufacture = m.id_manufacture AND m.name LIKE 'paint%'
WHERE pl.id_product IS NOT NULL OR 
      cl.id_category IS NOT NULL OR 
      m.id_manufacture IS NOT NULL;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT pl.name, cl.name, m.name 
FROM ps_product p 
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product 
INNER JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON p.id_category_default = cl.id_category 
INNER JOIN ps_manufacturer m ON p.id_manufacture = m.id_manufacture 
WHERE pl.name LIKE 'paint%' OR 
      cl.name LIKE 'paint%' OR 
      m.name LIKE 'paint%';
```

Comment: How Can I select only name. Because I have a large database and select * is doing slow.

Comment: @saharsh this wont match names if their id is not present in ps_product table so you wont get all the data required.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT x.id,y.name,z.name,a.name 
 FROM ps_product x 
 FULL OUTER JOIN ps_product_lang y 
 ON x.id_product = y.id_product 
 FULL OUTER JOIN ps_category_lang z
 ON x.id_category_default = z.id_category 
 FULL OUTER JOIN ps_manufacturer a 
 ON x.id_manufacture = a.id_manufacture 
 WHERE a.name LIKE 'paint%'
 OR y.name LIKE 'paint%'
 OR z.name LIKE 'paint%'
```

**Full outer join** is required here because you want to match all the names so it will get all the data and match with the pattern 'paint%' and display the matching rows. Try it out once